# How can I prevent Gnome from showing two windows when doing alt-tab? (c++ qt app)

Tags: c++, qt, gnome, qwidget, alt-tab

*(see edits)*

I'm developing a QT/c++ application under gnome.

The application a main window and QListBox child window.

Both of these windows show up as separate main windows when I alt-tab away from the application.

How can I make it so that only one window is shown when I (or later the user) uses alt-tab?

I am guessing this behavior comes because one main window doesn't clip the subwindow - the subwindow extends the boundary of the main window. Gnome has bad alt-tab behavior for a number of other applications too, showing modal dialog boxes separately from main windows. But in the case of my app, this is really annoying.

I am thinking I could make a giant transparent window that includes both existing windows. But it would be nicer to find a "clean" solution.

(the most logical guess is indeed that it has something to do with window flags. I've tried every reasonable combination of flags I could think of. The window types are described [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qt.html#WindowType-enum))

Edit:
The app has a QWidget as its main window (Not QMainWindow), QListView is contained in the QWidget object and created by passing a point to the main window. 
 is styled with Qt::Tool | Qt::FramelessWindowHint.

**Edit2:** The Qt::X11BypassWindowManagerHint style **does** work to remove the window from the alt-tab list. The problem is that it also makes the window "unmanaged" so it cover the other windows. I could manaully hide whenever I lose focus - prize now for a better solution.

Comment: I'm guessing it has something to do with the window flags... for instance, if you made it a tool window, would it grab both then?  When I use open office, for example, gnome doesn't tab through its floating tool windows, but only the main ones.

Comment: I'm assuming the QListBox has its parent window pointer set to a QMainWindow? Any chance at a skeleton of minimum-required code to generate this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating a window for your `QListBox` window set a `Qt::Tool` window flag in its constructor or later with `setWindowFlags` function call. Here is some code snippet(I omitted the headers):

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow mw;
    mw.show();
    QWidget toolWindow(&mw, Qt::Window|Qt::Tool);
    QHBoxLayout layout(&toolWindow);
    toolWindow.setLayout(&layout);
    QListView lv(&toolWindow);
    layout.addWidget(&lv);
    toolWindow.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

I've tested this on my Debian sid box (Gnome 2.30, metacity 2.30.1) with freshly created user: [image: image proof on answer to question #3553428].

If this is not what you wanted, then please name the software which works correctly or you may check it yourself. To do this run `xprop` in terminal window and click on the window you are interested in. The output will contain window flags. The one you are interested in is `_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE(ATOM)`. For the tool window(i.e. not listed in alt-tab) this flag is:

```
_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE(ATOM) = _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_UTILITY, _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_NORMAL
```

If the window with these flags is not a toolbox window then something is wrong with your window manager or you have personally set such behavior.

Comment: Well, you've got the only answer - the problem is, you are wrong. I'll just hold off. Maybe award it if you edit to reflect the comments in my question...

Comment: Well, I think the solution is as in my edits - you need to use the Qt::X11BypassWindowManagerHint style with all it's problems. But hey, if you've gone that much trouble, you're closer than anyone else...

Comment: But frickin stack overflow might have eaten the bonus since I can't see them appearing. Bad SO. This place ain't what it used to be...

Answer (score 1):

You can try it by hand with the wmctrl tool. With "-r -b SOMETHING" you can modify NET_WM arguments to it. Try these in [1].

If this works, you can add them in with Xlib-Calls (If you get to know X11 Window Number from Qt. I am sure that's possible).

```
[1] http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/1.3/ar01s05.html
```